# How do I sort a dynamic array in ascending order?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, dynamic

I have an assignment to have a user enter two number which are the size of the arrays then enter the elements for the arrays. Then I have to combine them into one array and sort them in ascending order. The catch is I have to do it with only dynamic arrays. I already combined the arrays and tried to sort them but it crashes every time on that part. This is my code to sort the array:

```
int *temp;
temp = &array1size;
for (int i = 0; i < *size1ptr; i++)
{

    for (int j = 0; j < *size1ptr - 1; j++)
    {
        if (*(finalarray + j) > *(finalarray + j + 1))
        {

            temp = &*(finalarray + j);
            *(finalarray + j) = *(finalarray + j + 1);
            *(finalarray + j + 1) = *temp;

        }
    }/*End inner for loop*/
}/*End outer for loop*/
```

IT crashes on this part and I cant figure out why. Here is some other code where I make the other arrays:

```
int array1size, array2size;
int *array1ptr, *array2ptr, *size1ptr, *size2ptr, *finalarray, *finalptr;

cout << "enter size of first array: ";
cin >> array1size;
size1ptr = &array1size;
array1ptr = new int[*size1ptr];

cout << "Enter array content: ";
for (int i = 0; i < *size1ptr; i++)
{
    cin >> *(array1ptr + i);
}

cout << "enter size of second array: ";
cin >> array2size;
size2ptr = &array2size;
array2ptr = new int[array2size];

cout << "Enter array content: ";
for (int i = 0; i < *size2ptr; i++)
{
    cin >> *(array2ptr + i);
}

finalarray = new int[*size1ptr];

for (int i = 0; i < *size1ptr; i++)
{
    *(finalarray + i) = *(array1ptr + i);
}
for (int i = 0; i < *size2ptr; i++)
{

    *size1ptr += 1;
    *(finalarray + *size1ptr - 1) = *(array2ptr + i);

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `finalarray = new int[*size1ptr + *size2ptr];` ?

Comment: I set the size of finalarray equal to the size of the first array becuase first I convert all elements of finalarray to equal the first array. Then when Im adding the second array into final array I increase the size of finalarray by one for each new element I put in

Comment: C style arrays (which are dynamically allocated, IE `new`ed and `delete`ed, aren't dynamic arrays, which std::vector is). You need to allocate for the final size, @HappyCoder is correct.

Comment: You could use `std::vector` and `std::sort` (unless your teacher forbids it). BTW, read more about [sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) (yours is aweful) and consider some [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you CANNOT dynamically grow the size of C-style arrays (use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if you are willing to achieve that)

In your case, you need to give the final size (sum of size of array1 and array2) of the final array at the time of creation, i.e.,

`finalarray = new int[*size1ptr + *size2ptr];`

Comment: Thanks so much to you and happycoder it works now :D I cant believe it tooks my hours to do this and thats all I had to change